# Button Unit Testing C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I want to test if my button is doing what it was expected. But I even can't test this simple example:

```
public int k = 0;

public void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    k = 1;
}
```

Unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ButtonClick3_ret1()
{
    //arrange
    int x;
    int expected = 1;

    //act
    int actual;
    Form c = new Form();
    c.button3.PerformClick();
    actual = c.k;

    //assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected,actual );
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How should I make it to work?

Comment: What about it isn't working? You haven't provided any details about what is wrong/broken/unexpected/errors/etc..

Comment: After performing click of button3 the value k still remain 0 for unit tester.

Comment: Have you put break points in the `button3_Click` event to see if it's getting hit? Are you sure that is actually wired to `button3`'s `Click` event?

Comment: @BrootsWaymb 99% probability that it's not wired, since he didn't mention any exceptions or other problems.

Comment: So, how shoul I check whether or not is wired?

Comment: There no errors in code, it's just returning a wrong value.

Comment: Do you have a Form named "Form"? Because that won't compile against a new System.Windows.Forms.Form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually subscribe your `button3` to the event in order for the event to actually be fired.

Click on the button in your designer (assuming you're using VS), then the lightening bolt in the Properties window, and select your event handler from the dropdown next to "Click".

Without subscribing to an event, your control has absolutely no knowledge of what it is supposed to do when it gets clicked (there is nothing to "map" `button3.Click` automatically to `button3_Click` in C#).

[image: properties window]

This works because you've already created something for `Click` to subscribe to. You can also generate something like `button3_Click` automatically by double clicking your button in the designer, if you haven't written the code for it yet (otherwise you'll get something like `button3_Click_1`).

Comment: Could you check it please?

Answer (score 0):

I just put c.Show(); and it returned the correct answer.
[Unit test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTg3U.png)